# Transform text in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, string, sql-server-2008

I am trying to create a dynamic query in SQL Server.

**Input:** `@value= abc,def,en,`

**Output:** `MAX(abc) as abc, MAX(def) as def, MAX(en) as en`

My efforts so far took me no where.

With CONVERT() and REPLACE() I achieved a bit but finding it difficult. Need help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [SQL User Defined Function to Parse a Delimited String](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7938/SQL-User-Defined-Function-to-Parse-a-Delimited-Str)

So you can do like

```
Declare @Value varchar(200) = 'abc,def,en'
Declare @Item varchar(20) = null
declare @Str varchar(1000)=''

WHILE LEN(@Value) > 0
BEGIN
    IF PATINDEX('%,%',@Value) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @Item = SUBSTRING(@Value, 0, PATINDEX('%,%',@Value))
       -- SELECT @Item
        IF(LEN(@Str)>0)
          SET @Str = @Str + ', SELECT MAX('+@Item+') as ' +@Item
        ELSE
          SET@Str = @Str + ' SELECT MAX('+@Item+') as ' +@Item

        SET @Value = SUBSTRING(@Value, LEN(@Item + ',') + 1, LEN(@Value))
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @Item = @Value
        SET @Value = NULL
        SET @Str = @Str + 'SELECT MAX('+@Item+') as ' + @Item
    END
END

select @Str
```

See the fiddle sample [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4e2a22/2)

Comment: I want the query string `MAX(abc) as abc, MAX(def) as def, MAX(en) as en` as the output

Comment: `SELECT MAX(` wasn't required, really great job. Thanks for the help.

Comment: in my input there will be a (,) at the end. if I run your code a (,) is getting added to the end how can I correct it. @huMptyduMpty

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
declare @value varchar(50) = 'abc,def,en'
declare @result varchar(100) = ''

select @result = replace(@value,'abc', 'MAX(''abc'') as abc')
select @result = replace(@result,'def', 'MAX(''def'') as def')
select @result = replace(@result,'en', 'MAX(''en'') as en')

select @result
```

You can also do the replacements in one line by nesting the expressions.

EDIT: If you have variable values in @value, you can take the below approach:

1. Use a splitter function to get the individual values in the string as a list. You can take a look at [this article](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) for implementations.
2. Insert this list to a temp table.
3. Update the temp table as shown above.
4. Concatenate the values into a single string using STUFF like so:

   `select stuff((select ',' + val from #temp for xml path('')),1,1,'')`

Comment: I may not get abc,def,en all the time!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Value VARCHAR(200) = 'abc,def,en'
DECLARE @Template VARCHAR(100) = 'MAX(''##'') as ##'
DECLARE @Result VARCHAR(1000) = ''
DECLARE @Data VARCHAR(100) = ''

WHILE LEN(@Value) > 0
BEGIN
    SET @Data = REPLACE(LEFT(@Value, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', @Value),0), LEN(@Value))),',','')
    SET @Result = @Result + REPLACE(@Template, '##', @Data)
    IF CHARINDEX(',', @Value) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @Result = @Result + ','
        SET @Value = REPLACE(@Value,@Data + ',','')
    END
    ELSE
        SET @Value = REPLACE(@Value,@Data,'')
END
SELECT @Result
```